# REST full API best practice Design

Tags: spring-boot, rest

I wonder what is the best practice for this business model is:

I have a `User` object and a `Post` object, the user has one or many Posts, so I want to know what's the best design:

1 - Create separate endpoints GET `/users/id` and GET `/posts?userId=id`

2 - Create only one endpoint GET `/users/id` and in my service layer call `getPostsByUserId()` then add posts to my user object and return them in the API.

could you tell me which is the right approach and the pros and cons?

Answer (score 0):

If you go with the first approach, Then you are using **Lazy fetching** which is common in RestApis and it's being used for one-to-many relationships where you want to get instances related to one entity; Simply it has better performance because your client fetches data as specified and as much as they needed. The second approach uses **Eager fetching** which is good for loading a single related instance. In the end, Your selection between these two is toughly close to your usage. In RestApis the first approach is the more common and better solution. But in traditional web applications like Spring MVC, In some situations, You have to use the second approach to load all necessary things on your page.